# Using Version Control solutions to manage files history which contain Date-Version in File Name

Tags: git, version-control, document-management

I need to create a structure to manage version and history tracking for Files that are, not binary file, has date and version in file name and has different status.

Example :

I have a file ( ABC_20160401_1) which first part is the main name , second is date and third is version in that date.
The file status may be change to Review , we copy file to another main folder called REVIEW, if the file changes, then by new name ABC_20160405_1 will send back to first folder. the first file ( ABC_20160401_1) must move to Archive Folder.

I can't change the naming convention, and trying to find a solution to use a Version controller such as Git, but I can't find a way to manage history of transferring between folders and how to keep relation between ABC_ .... Files with different version information in File Name.

Is there a proposal to create such a structure?

Comment: Git doesn't alter file names during the versioning process, at least not externally.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following command every time you want to change file name:-

git mv -f ABC_{CURRENT_TIME}*1 ABC*{CURRENT_TIME}_1